# Different methods give different answers Solve $ \sec x- 1 = (\sqrt 2 - 1) \tan x $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Solve $ \sec x- 1 = (\sqrt 2 - 1) \tan x $

## Case 1)

Square both the sides and  using $ \sec ^2 x = 1+ \tan^2 x. $ And solving the quadratic we get answer $\tan x = 1$ or $\tan x = 0$.
Putting them back in also solves the equation.

Thus $x$ is either $n \pi $ or $x =  n \pi + \frac{\pi}{4}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

## Case 2)

$ \sec x- 1 = (\sqrt 2 - 1) \tan x $

$ \frac{1-\cos x}{\cos x} = (\sqrt 2 - 1) \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} $

$ 2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}= (\sqrt 2 - 1) 2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}$

Thus solution is $\sin \frac{x}{2} = 0$ and $\tan \frac{x}{2} = \frac{\pi}{8}$

Thus $x$ is either $x = 2n \pi$
Or  $x = 2n\pi + \frac{π}{4}$

These two answer are not same.  So something is wrong.

Even though below question look similar to this one. None of the concepts in its answers really help this question.
[Different ways gives different results - solving $\tan 2a = \sqrt 3 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217928/different-ways-gives-different-results-solving-tan-2a-sqrt-3/3217947#3217947)

Comment: Case 1): $n\pi$ is not  a solution for $n$ odd.

Comment: $$\sqrt2-1=\dfrac{\sec x-1}{\tan x}=\csc x-\cot x$$

$$\iff\sqrt2+1=\csc x+\cot x$$ as $\csc^2x-\cot^2x=1$

$\implies\csc x=\sqrt2>0,\cot x=1>0$

So, $x$ in the first quadrant

$$\implies x=2n\pi+\dfrac\pi4$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring both sides of an equation can introduce extraneous solutions.  Substitution demonstrates that if $n$ is odd, then $x = n\pi$ is not a solution as $-2 \neq 0$ and that $x = n\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$ is not a solution as the LHS is negative while the RHS is positive.  On the other hand, direct substitution shows that your second method produces correct solutions.